# to have the women of his court speak frankly

Tags: meaning

> Toward the beginning of Denis Diderot's 1748 fable Les bijoux indiscrets (The Indiscreet Jewels), the genie Cucufa seeks to gratify the desire of the sultan Mangogul **to have the women of his court speak frankly of their sexual adventures**.

This is an extract from the book *Hard Core: Power, Pleasure and the Frenzy of Visible* by Linda Williams. I would like to know whether the highlighted passage is causative? Is my interpretation of this sentence correct? Cucufa wants to gratify Mangogul's pleasure by allowing the girls to speak frankly about their sexual adventures?

Answer (score 1):

> Toward the beginning of Denis Diderot's 1748 fable Les bijoux indiscrets (The Indiscreet Jewels), the genie Cucufa seeks to gratify **the desire** of the sultan Mangogul **to have the women of his court speak frankly** of their sexual adventures.

Yes, its a causative complement clause. But I would say not "allowing the girls to speak frankly of their adventures", but "**making** the girls speak frankly..".

The construction is akin to

> I have a desire to **have** my car repaired.